# What's the best input/edit method to handle small high precision numbers?

Tags: input-fields, html, numbers, data-entry

I have an [AG Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) with cells that contain very small highly precise numbers - eg 0.002957399184

I want to allow users to edit these numbers easily and accurately - basically want to avoid fiddling around trying to select using the cursor where you want/what you want to change.

I tried using a cell renderer which just consisted of an `<input type="number" />` but that only allows increments of a predefined step and they might want to add 0.1 or 0.001 for example.

Anyone have any ideas of how could I tackle this?

Comment: I edited your question to focus on the UX issue (which seems to be where your main problem at the moment), otherwise code implementation questions are off-topic.

Comment: related: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/105644/ui-for-inputting-numbers-efficiently

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the rare cases where an overwrite input (sometimes called overtype) comes in handy. You may have seen it before accidentally in office programs where hitting the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key toggles between insert and overwrite mode, or in some time controls (eg. in Audacity).

Overwrite mode lets the user select a character in one click (as opposed to space between character as the normal "insert" mode does), and then overwrite it immediately.

NB, it's not something supported natively in browsers, so you'll need to build it yourself. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23840099/2792952 may be useful.